# How to check if an .exe file is loade to execute it?

Tags: c#, exe

This may be a bit of a newbie question. I am loading a executable from a server and then want to execute this program. After execution is finished, I want to delete this file.

Here is part of my code:

```
 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (check == true)
                {
                    if (webBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("0"))
                    {
                        check = false;
                        // timer1.Stop();
                        button1.Enabled = true;
                        MessageBox.Show("Wrong HWID ");
                        this.Close();
                    }
        else if (webBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("1"))
        {
            check = false;
            // timer1.Stop();
            button1.Enabled = true;
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            Properties.Settings.Default.Serial = textBox1.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Installed = true;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            MessageBox.Show("All info correct!");
            var result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to start ?", "Application Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                wc.DownloadFileAsync(uri, filename);
            }



            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                Process.Start(filename);
            }
        }
 else if (webBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("2"))
                {
                    check = false;
                    // timer1.Stop();
                    button1.Enabled = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("HWID field left empty");
                }
                else if (webBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("3"))
                {
                    check = false;
                    // timer1.Stop();
                    button1.Enabled = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong serial");

                }
                else if (webBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("Object not found"))
```

Other related code:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://link.com/blabla/blabla.exe");
string filename = @"C:\Users\User\blabla.exe";
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to `await` the download.

Comment: yep mate, i just need some Direction

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with locking your current process this can be done synchronously. This is not the recommended way to do it but may work in your case depending on your environment.

Change this:

```
wc.DownloadFileAsync(uri, filename);
```

To this:

```
wc.DownloadFile(uri, filename);
```

After this you can add:

```
if (File.Exists(filename)) {
    Process process = Process.Start(filename);
    process.WaitForExit();

    File.Delete(filename);
}
```

Which will check to see if the file exists, starts it, waits for it to finish, and then deletes it. As always when working with FileIO, you should work to handle exceptions.

---

*This is the better apporach*

If it needs to be `async` then another way to do this may be to trigger an event when the download is complete. You would want to add an event handler like the following to your `WebClient`:

```
client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler (DownloadFileCallback);
```

And then add a handler method similar to the following:

```
private void DownloadFileCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)  {
    if (File.Exists(filename)) {
        Process process = Process.Start(filename);
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Note that in this handler method, `filename` is instance data to your class so you know where you saved the file. This should get you started in the right direction.

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in my answer, using `wc.DownloadFile()` is synchronous, meaning it will lock your current process. (i.e. you will see this when debugging when you step over this line it will not do anything else until it has finished). This can cause problems when the download (or more generally any synchronous process) takes a long, it has the potential to lock up your UI (if this is UI code). The best practice is to do this asynchronously which is what the original code you posted does. In the code you posted you were using `wc.DownloadFileAsync()`. To keep using this method, add an event handler like shown above and this handler method will be called once the download has completed. This makes the download run in the background so your thread is free to run other things while this is working. (i.e. this can leave your UI responsive on long downloads) Inside your event handler, your download is finished so you can continue on from there.

**EDIT 2:**

Since you will only be executing the program and then deleting it, it may be worth just saving it to the temp directory (navigate to `%temp%`). Something that may work to generate your `filename` would be the following:

```
string filename = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "MyFile.exe");
```

This should result in something like the following path `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\MyFile.exe`

Comment: the problem is that i already have a void. And i need to do everything there. I ask a question, load .exe, check if it's loaded, execute it, and delete it

Comment: @paxxa what do you mean you have a `void`?

Comment: Are you fine with locking your current thread up until the download completes? Otherwise you will need to do something outside of where you are writing the that code now.

Comment: hm actually, when i change wc.downloadfileasync(uri, filename); to wc.downloadfile(uri, filename); it works fine, but can you please tell me, is this a right method? because you told this is not a recomended way

Comment: @paxxa see my edit in the answer to clarify (was too long for a comment)

Comment: thanks mate, appreciate it. But a file is 20kb ...so i wont face any problem with downloading it. Maybe do you know how can i delete it afterall? i tried this File.Delete(filename); but of course doesn't work. because i need to know if the file is in process or no

Comment: I edited my answer under the synchronous part as to how you would do that. It is essentially the same code that would go into the event handler in the `async` version of this

Comment: Thanks mate, i got it. but what if i can't use a handler method, like in my code. I mean i maybe can, but i need to listen to text message "All info correct" and decide what to do below if i get it right

Comment: ah sorry for stupid questions, just coded it and everything working fine. but without handler..i will look into it and will find a way to implement it in my code...For now i faced another problem, i need to find out a c# exe folder path somehow and change with it filename path. I will try with System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);

Comment: @paxxa I edited my answer to include how you could get a valid path to save your file. Since it is a small file the first option may work in your case, but do some research on `async` in C#. That should be a decent starting path for you.

Comment: thx mate, but i have already solved all my problems, i can post it here, if needed) i just took a path from folder and added :\\..loader.exe and also solved problem with admin rights:) thank you!

Comment: @paxxa good to hear. If this answer helped you please mark it as the answer.